# Should i check quantity of battery liquid?

Tags: battery, nissan

The battery of my Nissan Tiida is similar to the ones in the pictures below. Should I check if there is enough liquid inside? and in case it needs, should I add distilled  water?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you taken the battery out? Does it have indicators for max and min battery fluid levels? How old is the battery?

Comment: I didn't take the battery. I think it doesn't has min ans max levels. It has two years old. The car has the same time, but I am checking most of the think that my knowledge let me do.

Comment: It seems like I have the exact same battery in my 2008 Jetta (1J0 915 105 AD) -- the only difference is that there's a sticker over these 6 caps, but the caps themselves are exactly the same; although mine also has an eye between the terminals.  Have you figured out what is the correct electrolyte level within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This battery type does not allow for easy checking and does not require it. If you had a battery with caps you could remove, then yes, you would use distilled water to top them off.

Comment: The batteries in the pictures both have caps - so you can check and fill.

Comment: @RoryAlsop ... sorry, I think I clearly stated that it *does not allow for **easy** checking* ... I never said you *couldn't* check them. These types of batteries do not lend itself to checking. I mean, check it if you like, but they do not require it.

Comment: @Paulster2, so, how would one check it?  I have the exact same caps on my "1J0 915 105 AD" (12V 61 Ah 330A DIN, 540A EN/SAE) battery, and after an unfortunate incident of draining it up, it looks like it cannot hold the charge anymore; I'm thinking of adding some water, but I wanted to make sure I don't add too much.

Comment: @cnst I believe you can unscrew the caps that are there by placing something broad like a putty knife into the slot and turning counter-clock-wise. The problem is, if your battery was drained (or partially drained), you'd need to put new acid in there, not water. Water alone would not be enough to get the battery working: you need the electrolytic action of the acid. If you have battery acid, you can fill it up to the split ring which should be present. You do this at your own risk, as acid is what acid is ... it will burn and destroy.

Answer (score 2):

While it is normally not required with a maintenance free battery yours may be a low maintenance type. Allowing the battery acid level to drop too low can cause the battery to overheat shortening its life. The small circles with the cross pattern on the top are caps. They can be removed and water can be added. It is best to use distilled water. If you don't have a battery filler you can use a plastic turkey baster. It is important to add a little at a time and not overfill the cells.

Comment: Using the turkey baster allows for more control and reduced risk of splashing acid. You can add small amounts into the dime sized hole easier than using an old soda bottle.

Comment: Just don't use the turkey baster for anything involved in cooking after that ;-)